# Targeting custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, terms

I have the following loop working as I want it but I need the 'activists' list item to include `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`.

What would be the best way to write this?

```
<?php

        $terms = array('news', 'activists', 'resources', 'posts' );

        if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                $my_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&post_type='.$term);

                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

                echo '<li class="item ' . $term . '">'; ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><strong><span><?php echo the_title(); ?></span></strong></a>

                <?php echo '</li>';

                endwhile; wp_reset_query();
            }

        }

        ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pieter's answer tells you what to do. As an aside, note that "Terms" has it's own meaning (in WP-Lingo, at least) and is not equivalent to "Post Type". Your variable-naming is suboptimal.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of  [`get_post_type( $post )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) to check whether a post belongs to a certain post type

Inside your loop, you can do the following check

```
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

if ( 'activists' == get_post_type() ) {

    /* Custom code for 'activists' post type. */

} else {

    /* Custom code for the other post types. */
}

endwhile; wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like OmAk suggested but I would add some fallback :

```
$activists_thumbs = has_post_thumbnail() ? the_post_thumbnail() : 'path/img_fallback.jpg';
```

It's better to check if you have something before actually using it.

**EDIT:** `wp_reset_postdata()` is enough (instead of `wp_reset_query()` )

Comment: Make "maybe" a "definitely" an I'd upvote this.

Comment: It's done now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
```

This will place the featured image with a link to the main post.

More details about how you can use `image_size` when calling the function: [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)